# C - Code injection using MapViewOfFile

Tags: memory, code-injection, portable-executable

A lot of tutorials about adding additional code into a physical file use `MapViewOfFile` to get the mapping of a file into the memory.

My question is really simple: how the final physical file is generated, as all operations are made directly from the memory?

A detailled code sample may be found here : http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/33006-detailed-guide-to-pe-infection/

My opinion is that I may be wrong about the function `MapViewOfFile`. Maybe it does not instantiate anything in the memory, but make a sort of "preview" of any memory instance of the file.

Thanks

Comment: In short, modifying the memory will cause the file to be modified as well.

Comment: Are you sure about it? Modifying an "instance" of memory in not the same as modifying the file in the hard-drive.

Comment: Pages of a file are mapped into memory by the OS as needed. Since it is a R+W mapping, modified pages will get written back out when flushed.